# Can't add my custom user control in main windows WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I can't add My user control to MainWindow.xaml

This is my solution explorer : (pointer show my user Control)

[image: Solution Explorer]

This is my user control header xaml file

```
<UserControl x:Class="SIManager.ucAddDevices"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SIManager"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="500" d:DesignWidth="500" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" FontFamily="B Nazanin">
```

And this is MainWindows Header Xaml

```
<Window x:Class="SIManager.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SIManager"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="600" Width="800">
```

And now I can`t add my user control to tab item ... Why ?

In picture below My user control name wont appear ... !!!!

[image]

how I can add my user control to Tab  Item ????

Comment: Did you rebuild after creating your user control ?

Comment: Yeah you should try cleaning the solution then rebuilding it, sometimes Intellisense doesn't recognize controls before a build

Comment: I Clean And Rebuilt Solution But Wont Work ....

Comment: Try restarting visual studio also. If that doesn't work make sure that the namespace of the usercontrol is correct in its code behind file. Also try just typing it in manually and see if its just intellisense giving issues.

Answer (score 1):

My user control Constructor gets params and won't appear in XAML.

I removed params from the user control Constructor and rebuilt the solution and it worked.

```
public ucAddDevices(MainWin win)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    mainWindow = window;
}
```

To:

```
public ucAddDevices() => InitializeComponent();
```